# Getting subtotal issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, subtotal

I have problem with the subtotal from the image below:
[image]

I have `28.45` , which is calculated in this function from : `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid`

```
    public function getSubtotalWithDiscount()
    {
        $address = $this->getQuoteAddress();
        if ($this->displayTotalsIncludeTax()) {
            $subtotalInclTax = $address->getSubtotal() + $address->getTaxAmount()
                    + $address->getHiddenTaxAmount() + $this->getDiscountAmount();
            return $subtotalInclTax;
        } else {
            return $address->getSubtotal() + $this->getDiscountAmount();
        }
    }
```

and `28.56` , which is calculated in the same class , in this function:

```
public function getSubtotal()
{
    $address = $this->getQuoteAddress();
    if ($this->displayTotalsIncludeTax()) {
        if ($address->getSubtotalInclTax()) {
            return $address->getSubtotalInclTax();
        }
        return $address->getSubtotal()+$address->getTaxAmount();
    } else {
        return $address->getSubtotal();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Normally I should have the same values. In my case the `$address->getHiddenTaxAmount()` and `$this->getDiscountAmount()` are `0` . So i only have `$subtotalInclTax = $address->getSubtotal() + $address->getTaxAmount()` for my first total (`28.45`) and in the second function I have this IF condition:

```
 if ($address->getSubtotalInclTax()) {
     return $address->getSubtotalInclTax();
 }
```

My question is why I'm getting the return value from that IF condition ? If it doesn't go inside it , it would return `return $address->getSubtotal()+$address->getTaxAmount();` and everything would be perfect :)

Thank you!